# Why there's a missing part error in YouTube Data API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Why there is this error in the YouTube Data API script:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\YoutubeApi\main.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Path\YoutubeApi\main.py", line 40, in main
    request = youtube.videos().update(
  File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 1012, in method
    raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "part"
```

The total output of the file in the console:

```py
Loading Credentials From File...
Refreshing Access Token...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\YoutubeApi\main.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Path\YoutubeApi\main.py", line 40, in main
    request = youtube.videos().update(
  File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 1012, in method
    raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "part"
```

**Main.py**

```py
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():
    # part 1 : store the user credentials
    credentials = None
    # token.pickle stores the user's credentials from previously successful logins
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        print('Loading Credentials From File...')
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)

    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            print('Refreshing Access Token...')
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            print('Fetching New Tokens...')
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json',
                scopes=[
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
                ]
            )
            #  part 2 : change the video title and run the server
            flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent',
                                authorization_prompt_message='')
            credentials = flow.credentials

            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
                print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
                pickle.dump(credentials, f)

    youtube = build('youtube','v3',credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().update(
        body={
            "id": "OSxK-tscmVA",
            "snippet":{
                "title":"It's Changed!",
            }
        }
    )

    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Script Explanation:**

What the script does is that if there's no file named `token.pickle` it will ask the user to authorize the application and the script will store the user credentials in `token.pickle` file so that the user doesn't have to authorize the application on every single run and the  `part 2` of the script changes my YouTube video's title.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is straightforward: as per the official specification of the [`Videos.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) API endpoint, the `part` request [parameter is required](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#parameters).

Therefore your call to `Videos.update` should look like the one below instead:

```json
request = youtube.videos().update(
    part = "snippet",
    body = {
        "id": "OSxK-tscmVA",
        "snippet": {
            "title":"It's Changed!",
        }
    }
)
```

Notice the added line `part = "snippet"`. This is the reason of the endpoint's complain.

Comment: the `part = "snippet"' you asked to add threw me another error. the error was too long for the comment. you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68751921/youtube-data-api-error-when-changing-video-title)

Comment: @Knight_Crawler: The fix I have shown you above **is required by the official spec**. This code changed fixes your error `Missing required parameter "part"`. Even though I linked above the official spec of `Videos.list`, you seem not inclined to use it: the [request body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#request-body) of your call to the endpoint **needs to specify the video category ID too** for to be accepted by the API backend.

Comment: @Knight_Crawler: Note that the [`update_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py) sample code from Google has all this things in it. I warned you from the get go that you **have to absorb** (i.e. **understand**) that code. There's no other way than going through reading carefully the official documentation.