# Youtube data api error when changing video title

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

why did i get this error on the script given below:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\YoutubeApi\main.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Path\YoutubeApi\main.py", line 49, in main
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 937, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&alt=json returned "The <code>snippet.categoryId</code> property specifies an invalid category ID. Use the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list">videoCategories.list</a></code> method to retrieve supported categories.". Details: "[{'message': 'The <code>snippet.categoryId</code> property specifies an invalid category ID. Use the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list">videoCategories.list</a></code> method to retrieve supported categories.', 'domain': 'youtube.video', 'reason': 'invalidCategoryId', 'location': 'body.snippet.categoryId', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

Main.py

```py
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():
    credentials = None
    # token.pickle stores the user's credentials from previously successful logins
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        print('Loading Credentials From File...')
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)

    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            print('Refreshing Access Token...')
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            print('Fetching New Tokens...')
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json',
                scopes=[
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'
                ]
            )

            flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent',
                                authorization_prompt_message='')
            credentials = flow.credentials

            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
                print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
                pickle.dump(credentials, f)

    youtube = build('youtube','v3',credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().update(
        part = 'snippet',
        body={
            "id": "OSxK-tscmVA",
            "snippet":{
                "title":"It's changed",
            }
        }
    )
    

    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Script Explanation:**

What the script does is that if there's no file named token.pickle it will ask the user to authorize the application and the script will store the user credentials in token.pickle file so that the user doesn't have to authorize the application on every single run and the part 2 of the script changes my YouTube video's title.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you seem not inclined to make use of the official specification of the [`Videos.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) API endpoint:

The [request body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#request-body) of your call to the endpoint **needs to specify the video category ID too** for to be accepted by the API back-end.

Note that the [`update_video.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py) sample code from Google -- that I indicated you at the beginning of your series of posts as valuable source of information -- has all these required things in it.

Again, please acknowledge that you *have to absorb* (i.e. *understand*) that code. There's no other way than going through *reading carefully the official documentation*.